# Some questions about linux signals

Tags: linux, signals

1. Is (`SIGRTMIN + 1`) safe for inter-process communication? Will it change in different processes?
2. Are there any differences to use `sigqueue(2)` or `kill(2)` to send standard signals and real time signals?
   If I use `sigqueue(2)` to send a series of `SIGUSR1`(standard signals) and handle them slowly, are there mutiple instances of `SIGUSR1` in the queue?
   What about using `kill(2)` to send `SIGRTMIN`(real time signals)? Will they be queued?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sigqueue() can be used to send only real time signals and kill() can be used to send only standard signals. I haven't tried sending the wrong signal with either API. But I would expect it to fail with some appropriate errno. Linux doesn't queue standard signals. Real time signals are queued. The max number of real time signals that can be queued is defined as **RLIMIT_SIGPENDING**

You can use any real time signal as long as the receiver has the handler setup for the particular signal sender is sending.

**EDIT**

I was wrong earlier in my answer. It looks like kill() can send real-time signals too. But from the comment in __send_signal() it looks like using kill to send real-time signals might not have the desired effect in some cases, ie: signals may not get queued.

```
   /*
     * Real-time signals must be queued if sent by sigqueue, or
     * some other real-time mechanism.  It is implementation
     * defined whether kill() does so.  We attempt to do so, on
     * the principle of least surprise, but since kill is not
     * allowed to fail with EAGAIN when low on memory we just
     * make sure at least one signal gets delivered and don't
     * pass on the info struct.
     */
```

Comment: Is it by experience, by reading the kernel source code, or by reading Posix specifications? If you have some sources, it would be interesting to share them...

Comment: But the fact is both `kill(2)` and `sigqueue(2)` can send any signals without failure. I wrote a small test to prove they work. But I don't know how to post source code in a comment.

Answer (score 6):

This post is old news, but it ranked high on Google and is unfortunately misleading so here are some clarifications:

1. One can send any signal with any of those functions
2. sigqueue enables passing some more "context" [e.g. information, @see siginfo et. al], as opposed to kill/raise
3. As per the real time signals - it doesn't matter if they are sent or queued - they will behave the same [e.g. queued cf. grouped as with the non RT signals]